# Delete "2 duplicated" elements at once from a sorted linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
void del_duplicated(struct node *first) {
    struct node *current = listfirst, *prev = listfirst, *tmp;
    if (current == NULL)
        printf("Nothing to delete !\n");
    while (current != NULL) {
        /* Keeping traverse the list to find the duplicated elements. */
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;

        /* for the first and second duplicated node such as 1 1 2 3 5 */
        if (prev->data == listfirst->data && current->data == listfirst->data) {
            listfirst = current->next;
            printf("LIST FIRST NOW AT %d", listfirst->data);
        }
        /* The rest requirement such as 1 2 4 4 5 convert to 1 2 5 */
        else if ((prev->next)->data == (current->next)->data) {
            (prev->next) = (current->next)->next;  /*this is point 2 to 5*/
            tmp = current;                 /*delete the node*/
            free(tmp);
            tmp = current->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a linked list problem which requires me to delete "2 duplicated node" from the list.
Which is like `1 1 2 3 5` convert to `2 3 5`.
And `1 2 4 4 5` will be converted to `1 2 5`.

But my program crashes because the pointer points to a strange place and I don't know why. (.exe has stopped working)
I think my logic of move pointer is OK but....[error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG8A1.jpg)
My logic is attached in the comments of my source code.

I'm a student new at programming and studying computer science in Taiwan.
Please forgive my bad English.

**Edit** after 1 hour.

I added BREAK into both of my judge statements and it worked well.
But I dont know why.

```
void del_duplicated(struct node *first) {
    struct node *current = listfirst, *prev = listfirst, *tmp, *tmp2;
    if (current == NULL)
        printf("Nothing to delete !\n");
    while (current != NULL) {
        /* Keeping traverse the list to find the duplicated elements. */
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
        //printf("prev %d,current %d\n", prev->data, current->data);
        //system("pause");
        /* for the first and second duplicated node such as 1 1 2 3 5 */
        if (prev->data == listfirst->data && current->data == listfirst->data) {
            listfirst = current->next;
            system("pause");
            break;
        }
        /* The rest requirement such as 1 2 4 4 5 convert to 1 2 5 */
        else if (current->data == (current->next)->data) {
            (prev->next) = (current->next)->next;  /* this is point 2 to 5 */
            tmp = current->next;
            tmp2 = current;                 /* delete the node */
            current = (current->next)->next;
            free(tmp);
            free(tmp2);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your English is very good. You sould take some time to **learn to debug**. It will save you countless  hours of "why is this not working"

Comment: If your list does not have a dummy 1st node (meaning that your first node holds the value `1` in your first example), then you are changing the list address when you delete your first node. You must pass the address of the list to your function to do this. e.g. `void del_duplicated(struct node **first)`. Otherwise, when you delete the first node, you have no reference to your list back in `main()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D I will!!! I just learn C 4 months ago ~

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node NODE;
struct node{
    int         data;
    NODE        *next;
    NODE        *prev;
};


NODE * find_node( NODE *first, int value){
    while( first ){
        if( first->data == value )
            return first;
        first = first->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

NODE* delete_node( NODE  **pnd ){

    NODE *tmp, *nd;

    if(!pnd || !*pnd)
        return  NULL;

    nd  =      *pnd;
    tmp =      nd->next;



    if(nd->next)
        nd->next->prev =    nd->prev;

    if(nd->prev)
        nd->prev->next =    nd->next;

   free( nd );

   *pnd=NULL;

   return tmp;
}


void del_duplicated( NODE **first ) {
    NODE    *tmp,
            *dup,
            *current=*first;
    int val;
    while( current ){

        dup =   find_node(tmp,current->data);   // find in next nodes
        tmp =   current->next;
        val=    current->data;
        while(1){
            dup=find_node(tmp,val);
            if(!dup) break;

            while(dup){                         // delete all occurences
                if(dup == tmp)
                    tmp = dup->next;
                delete_node(&dup);
                dup=find_node(tmp,val);
            }
            delete_node(&current);              // delete current one aswell
       }     
       current=tmp;                                 

    }
}


NODE *new_node(NODE *parent,int value){

    NODE *nd =  malloc( sizeof( NODE ) );
    nd->prev =  parent;

    if( parent ){
        nd->next =      parent->next;
        if(parent->next)
            parent->next->prev =    nd;

        parent->next =  nd;
    }else
        nd->next =      NULL;

    nd->data =          value;

    return nd;

}



void free_nodes(NODE *root){
    NODE    *tmp;

    if(root && root->prev){
        root->prev->next =  NULL;
    }
    while(root){
        tmp =               root;
        root =              root->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

void print_nodes( NODE *root, char *text){

    if(text)
        printf("%s:\n", text);

    while( root ){
        printf("%d ", root->data );
        root =  root->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main( void ){
    NODE        *root;
    root =      new_node(NULL,10);

    new_node( root, 25);
    new_node( root, 25);
    new_node( root, 25);
    new_node( root, 20);
    new_node( root, 15);
    new_node( root, 16);
    new_node( root, 16);
    new_node( root, 5);

    print_nodes( root ,"\nWith duplicated items");
    del_duplicated(&root);
    print_nodes( root ,"\nDuplicated items removed");

    free_nodes(root);
    return 0;
}
```